# Show that the equation $\lambda - z - e^{-z} = 0$ has exactly one solution in the half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation, rouches-theorem

I know that this question has been asked before, but I'm not satisfied with the answers provided. I will post here my complete solution to this question, but I'm not very sure about my (a) and (c) parts.

Let $\lambda > 1$ and show that (a) the equation $\lambda - z - e^{-z} = 0$ has exactly one solution in the half plane $\{z: \Re(z) > 0\}$. (b) Show that this solution must be real. (c) What happens to the solution as $\lambda \to 1$?

Let f(z) = $\lambda - z - e^{-z}$

(a) The equation $f(z) = 0$ has exactly one solution in the half plane $\{z: \Re(z) > 0\}$.

Assume that $\exists z_0 \in G = \{z:\Re(z) > 0 \}$ such that $f(z_0) = 0$, we will show that this is the only solution in $G$.

$$f(z_0) = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda - z_0 = e^{-z_0} \Rightarrow |z_0 - \lambda| = e^{-\Re(z_0)}$$

But $Re(z_0) > 0$, thus

$$|z_0 - \lambda| < 1$$

Consider $h(z) = -e^{-z}, g(z) = \lambda - z$,

$$|h(z) + g(z)| = | \lambda - z - e^{-z} | \leq |e^{-z}| + |\lambda - z| = |h(z)| + |g(z)|$$

Hence, by Rouche's Theorem

$$Z_h + P_h = Z_g + P_g$$

But $P_h = P_g = 0$. Since $g$ has only one zero in $|z - \lambda| < 1$, $h + g = f(z)$ has only one zero also. $\square$

(b) Show that the solution is real

Consider the real function

$$f(x) = \lambda - x - e^{-x}$$

Then $f(0) = \lambda - 1 > 0$ and $f(\lambda) = -e^{-\lambda} < 0$, thus by the Intermediate value theorem,

$$\exists z_0 \in (0,\lambda), \mbox{ such that } f(z_0) = 0.$$

But this solution is unique by part (a), hence $f$ has a unique real solution in $G$.$\square$

(c) What happen to the solution $\lambda \to 1$?

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\lambda \to 1}f(z_0) & = \lim_{\lambda \to 1}0 \\
1 - z_0 - e^{-z_0} & = 0 \\
z_0 + e^{-z_0} = 1
\end{align*}
$$

Hence, $z_0 \to 0$ as $\lambda \to 1$. $\square$

My problem is that I can not see how we apply here the rouche theorem for make the claim about the roots of $f$ when we only consider $h$ and $g$ and not $f$. That point is not very clear to me.

Comment: Are you sure about that? $$|h(z) + g(z)| = | \lambda - z - e^{-z} | = |e^{-z}| + |z - \lambda| = |h(z)| + |g(z)|$$

Comment: that and also i don't understand why $$|\lambda-z-e^{-z}|=|e^{-z}|+|z-\lambda|$$

Comment: triangle ---inequality--- not triangle equality, should be $\leq$

Comment: I'm really not sure, but I think you need a strict inequality in order to use Rouche's theorem right?

Comment: An alternative approach:
$$\lambda-z=e^z$$
$$(\lambda-z)e^{\lambda-z}=e^\lambda$$
$$\lambda-z=W_k(e^\lambda)$$
$$z=\lambda-W_k(e^{\lambda})$$
At $k=0$, the solution is the real solution you want.  From there, you could probably use the [series expansions of the product log](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/06/01/) and find bounds on them.

Comment: @yanko I posted the solution to the problem below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Part (b) of this problem was not correct. I figured out how to solve my own problem by doing the following:

Consider $g(z) = -\lambda + z$,

$$
|f(z) + g(z)| = | \lambda - z - e^{-z} + -\lambda + z | = |-e^{-z}| 
$$

Then

$$
|f(z)| + |g(z)| = |\lambda - z - e^{-z}| + |-e^{-z}| 
$$

Thus,

$$
|f(z) + g(z)| = |-e^{-z}| < |f(z)| + |g(z)| = |f(z)| + |e^{-z}|
$$

Hence, by Rouche's Theorem

$$
Z_f + P_f = Z_g + P_g
$$

But $P_f = P_g = 0$. Since $g$ has only one zero in $|z - \lambda| < 1$, then $f(z)$ has only one zero also.$\square$

Answer (score 6):

[For completeness sake]

Since $\lambda > 1$, note that $ \gamma \doteq \partial B(\lambda,1) $ is in the right semi-plane.

Consider the functions $f(z) = e^z + z - \lambda $ and $g(z) = \lambda - z$, as above.

Notice that **at $\{\gamma\}$** we have:

$$
|f(z) + g(z)| = |e^z| < 1 = |g(z)| < |f(z)| + |g(z)|
$$

then by Rouché, since $f$ and $g$ don't have any poles, $f$ must have **exactly** one zero  $\beta \in B(\lambda,1)$, just like $g$.

On the other hand, let $\alpha $ in the right semi-plane be a root of $f$, 
$$
|\lambda - \alpha| =  
|e^\alpha| < 1 
\implies 
\alpha \in B(\lambda,1) 
\implies 
\alpha = \beta 
$$

then $\alpha$ is unique.