# Show that there is only one zero, and its real.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How can I proof that $z=\lambda-e^{-z}$ has only one zero and it is real?

**Edit:** For now, I supposed that $z=x$ with $x$ real, and defined $f(z)=\lambda-e^{-x}-x$. Now I use Bolzano's theorem: $$f(0)=\lambda-1>0\\ f(\lambda)=-e^{-\lambda}<0$$
So there's $c\in(0,\lambda): f(c)=0$

I suppose that exist another number  $b\in(0,\lambda): f(b)=0$. Now, $f'(z)=-1+e^{-x}$, using Rolle's theorem, I have that  exists  $d\in(0,\lambda): f'(d)=0$, but thats not true. So $c$ is the only root. Now i dont know how tro show that there aren't complex roots.

Comment: $x+e^{-x}$ has a minimum at $x=0$ at height $1$. There is no real solution for $λ<1$ and always 2 solutions for $λ>1$. See under related for similar questions with more conditions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/320055/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2380499/115115

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MathSE! In order to get good answer and no downvotes (I hate them, but these are the rules here :'( ), please, add more details to all you questions, as well as a brief description of your efforts.

Comment: You can't prove a false statement. For real $\lambda<1$, the equation has no real roots, for $\lambda>1$ it has two real roots. Concerning the absence of complex roots, I wouldn't dare a guess.

Comment: One has $(z-λ)e^{z-λ}=-e^{-λ}$, so that with the well-known Lambert-W function with its two branches $z=λ+W(-e^{-λ})$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation can be transformed to
$$
(z-λ)e^{z-λ}=-e^{-λ}
$$
which has the form
$$
ve^v=u
$$
which is the defining equation for the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). You question is thus for the nature of the branches $W_k(u)$ for values $u\in(-e^{-1},0)$.